# In MYSQL how do UPDATE a GROUP BY with a subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `veggies` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`qty` int(8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

we have a table `veggies`:

```
select * from veggies;
+----+--------+-----+
| id | name   | qty |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | melon  |   5 |
|  2 | carrot |   8 |
|  3 | melon  |   7 |
|  4 | pea    |   4 |
+----+--------+-----+
```

and when we SUM(`qty`) and GROUP BY `name`, it comes as:

```
SELECT name, SUM(qty) as sum_qty FROM veggies GROUP BY name;

+--------+----------+
| name   |  sum_qty |
+--------+----------+
| carrot |        8 |
| melon  |       12 |
| pea    |        4 |
+--------+----------+
```

now how do we UPDATE the table by subtracting -2, WHERE 'name' = 'melon'. And get the result as:

```
+--------+----------+
| name   |  sum_qty |
+--------+----------+
| carrot |        8 |
| melon  |       10 |
| pea    |        4 |
+--------+----------+
```

can we UPDATE tables with GROUP BY or do we need to use another method to query such statements?, and what is the simplest way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your original table has four rows.  Are you trying to delete a row?

Comment: Do you wish to subtract 1 from every name like 'melon' ? What if there are 3 rows of data with name 'melon'?

Comment: iv created a table called `veggies` with id, name and quantity.
and when i SELECT * FROM TABLES it comes four rows, and when i group by 
with SUM() function it comes as 3 rows, i want to deduct a quantity from the sum_qty column

Comment: The best answer is to update your table to have no duplicate names imo.

Comment: `Select name, case when name = 'melon' then sum_qty - 2 else sym_qty end sum_qty from (your query here) x`

Comment: Do you want to subtract 2 where name = 'melon' even if the sum is say 9 instead of 12?

Comment: the eg  is, its from a shop, and when we sell a veg, the quantity should be deducted from the item, 2 is a variable, it could be any number

Comment: So when you sell a veg isn't this transaction recorded in a table so the quantity sold can be deducted from the veggies table?

Comment: yep, when I (update veggies set qty = qty -1 where name = 'melon';)
it subtracts from 2 id's, named: melon.

this is not the desired result

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're trying to remove quantity from only one row, so that when you `SUM()` later, the result is 2 less. The best way to do this is to `LIMIT 1` your result set;

```
UPDATE veggies
SET qty = qty - 2
WHERE name = 'melon'
LIMIT 1;
```

Be warned that without a specific `ORDER` clause, the particular row that is updated cannot be guaranteed and may not be the same each time you execute this query.

---

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM veggies;
```

```
| id  | name   | qty |
| --- | ------ | --- |
| 1   | melon  | 3   |
| 2   | carrot | 8   |
| 3   | melon  | 7   |
| 4   | pea    | 4   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mX1DFAFXZYsBtigVQa4pUK/0)

---

You might also want to consider adding an additional conditional; `AND qty >= 2`, to prevent getting negative values. It would also be sensible to add a unique key on `name` so that you only have one row per veg, thus avoiding the problem altogether.

Comment: thank. for the answer, the reason i didn't use UNIQUE is because, we might have 'melon' or either veg from more than 1 vendor and it should be recorded in the dB, 

I included one table for sake of simplicity, actually its a one to many related, with a `vendor` table. And the `veggies` table will include a `vend_id` column

Comment: makes sense. it does feel wrong to arbitrarily pick a row to update as information gets lost (which vendor's product did you actually sell and how much of it do you have left?), but that is out of the scope of the question and possibly of your application too.

Comment: yep, we only want to add vegs and deduct, which vendors veg we sold is not needed, but we want to know how much is left after a certain veg is sold..

Comment: right now m trying grouping the veg `name` and trying to subtract a amount from it, and the result is not what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Strawberries comment above. I believe this is what you are looking for

```
Select name, 
sum(case name when 'melon' then sum_qty - 2 else sum_qty end)
as new_qty
from (SELECT b.name, SUM(b.qty) as sum_qty 
FROM veggies as b GROUP BY name) b group by b.name;


+--------+---------+
| name   | new_qty |
+--------+---------+
| carrot |       8 |
| melon  |      10 |
| pea    |       4 |
+--------+---------+
```